# Is /Library/Application Support Library accessible to all users?

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, mono

I need to place a file in `/Library/Application Support` so that the data stored in there can be accessed by my application irrespective of the user who is using the Mac.So i plan to create a directory within `/Library/Application Support` and  place the data file in it.

Is root privileges required to make a folder and place a file in this directory.I tried writing a file using

```
string s=System.IO.Path.Combine (Environment.GetFolderPath  (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "Library");

System.IO.File.Copy ("myfile.rtf", s + "//Application Support//kk.rtf");
```

The file was written successfully.Im a noob when it comes to Macintosh.. will all users be able to write this file provided that it worked when i tried.

Comment: I can't create a file in that folder, so I assume not.  Why not use /Users/Shared?

Comment: @Jason Thanks.okay... Im running on a VM and i assume there may be some modifications in the OSX version im using.Is this directory persistent and writeable and readable to all users with no root previlages? Basically im trying to store license data in it.

Comment: FYI: /Users/Shared is not guaranteed to work, OS-X placed through the enterprise lock down model do not have the /User/Shared default, nor the /User/Guest, etc...

Answer (score 1):

/Library is rwx and owned by root and rx to others (wheel group)

i.e.:

```
drwxr-xr-x+  73 root           wheel    2482 Jul 26 11:15 Library
```

Items within that directory are supposed to only be:

```
drwxr-xr-x  root  wheel
```

But a lot of third-party application break that during their install and flag their directory (and subs) as "rwxrwxr-x" and put in the admin group (like Parallels).... This, along with placing things in /usr/bin, etc.. will break on "El Capitan" this fall.

Now, "Application Support" within /Library is "drwxr-xr-x root  admin" and during a 'normal install', you would supply an admin password and the software installer creates a sub-dir there for its own usage/storage, usually flagged as "drwxrwxr-x  root admin" so all users can read and write there.

Now a user's home based "Application Support" is free game to r/w but that is only for the current user and changes there are not visible to others, and thus most apps have local preferences to override the global Application Support (same deal as the Windows registry).

So, placing a lic file for everyone on that machine to share, global Application Support would be the way to go, you just need to create a r/w directory for your application during your install.

BTW: Placing individual files in Application Support is a no-no, only directories that that level, so copying something like in your example "/Library/Application Support/kk.rtf" is wrong, create your own app sub-directory and than save kk.rtf there.

Comment: Thanks a lot.But im still confused here.Isnt this directory global "/Library/Application Support/" ? I mean if i put something there wont all users have access to it.Also what about putting the file in /Users/Shared? Im only targeting Mac 10.7 or upper.

Comment: Yes, "/Library/Application Support" is 'global', rwx to root and rx to everyone else, just make a sub-dir there for your application and place the license file there. But you will made 'admin' access to create the dir first, that is one reason installers prompt for admin access (create the dir with rwx perms). That help?

Comment: yeah it helped.But i did not understand your argument on the Users/Shared folder. Doesn't this folder exist by default in Mac.

Comment: By Default, yes it does. But its existence is not guaranteed after that as it can be removed/perms changed, some of Apple's enterprise best practice white papers and third-party security lock downs remove that as an option due to the 'open' security issues it has out of the box. For 'normal' installs/users, yes it 'should' be available...

Comment: hmm... do you mind elaborating that... I'm confused.

Comment: @l'L'l  do you mind sharing your opinion on the third comment RobertN has about 'Users/Shared' folder just below the question.