# ForceDirectories fails to create folders in MacOS Application Support

Tags: macos, delphi

Delphi XE7

```
var
  theFolder: String;
...
theFolder := System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(GetMacApplicationSupportDir, 'com.bookup.mychessapp' + Pathfinder;

ShowMessage(theFolder);

if ForceDirectories(theFolder)
  then ShowMessage('It worked.')
  else ShowMessage('It failed.');
```

ShowMessage now says it worked.

theFolder is '/Users/mike/Library/Application Support/com.bookup.chessopeningswizardprofessional/'

That reverse URL matches the Bundle identifier in the app's info.plist.

However, even though ForceDirectories() reports success, the folder does not appear in Macintosh HD | Library | Application Support (which has the folders for all the other apps).

Comment: What is the actual string value you are passing to ForceDirectories?  Assign it to a local string variable and the pass the local variable so you can examine it easier.

Comment: I was about to say you should call `GetLastError`, but that only works on Windows. Not sure how that would work on OSX.

Comment: @DaveOlson I've edited the question to include the exact string.

Comment: @MikeatBookup - In my answer to your question yesterday: [Get the MacOS Application Support folder in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45618686/get-the-macos-application-support-folder-in-delphi/45619951); I show how to retrieve the *User's* App Support Dir.  You want the *System's* App Support Dir.  I've updated the other answer to show both options.

Answer (score 1):

You want the Application Support directory under the System's Library directory, not the User's.

Your `GetMacApplicationSupportDir` function is probably passing `NSUserDomainMask` and is thus retrieving the Application Support directory under the **User's** Library directory.

You should use `NSSystemDomainMask` if you want the Application Support directory under the **System's** Library directory.

---

If ForceDirectories is still failing using the System level Application Support directory then you may not have appropriate admin (root) rights to create directories and files there.  This operation would typically be performed by and install process (which would have prompted for elevated admin/root rights.)

Have a look at this question; it seems to be addressing a similar issue:

[Is /Library/Application Support Library accessible to all users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900852/is-library-application-support-library-accessible-to-all-users)

Comment: The Finder on my Mac shows a number of application folders in the Library/Application Support/ folder (for Google, Adobe, VMWare, etc.).

Comment: When I do switch to NSSystemDomainMask the Mac returns... 

/Library/Application Support/com.bookup.chessopeningswizardprofessional/ 

Two things: first, the call to ForceDirectories now fails. Second, the Finder does not show an Application Support folder inside the System | Library folder.

Comment: It possible you are having a rights issue; I've updated the answer and pointed to a older question that seems to deal with a similar issue.